# WSO2 Registry Load Balanced URL?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

We have deployed WSO2 in clustered mode on two nodes. We are using external load balancer instead of internal elastic load balancer for traffic. How can we define this external load balanced URL in the config so that email notifications get the correct URL instead of individual nodes?

Thanks.

Comment: Question is not clear to me, have you clustered it in a Worker manger mode? and what do you mean by External load balanced URL in the config? do you mean ESB synapse config ?

Comment: By External Load Balancer, a third party Load Balancer, not WSO2's ELB. We have a third party hardware load balancer & all our load balancing is configured on it, so in our case for WSO2 we did the Work Members config to get them talking correctly, but we did not setup the ELB as its outside but i needed to config the LoadBalanced URL somewhere as though the loadbalanced URL was re-directing to one of the nodes correctly, any emails or interactions were generating URLs directing back to individual nodes causing confusion. Updating carbon.xml with HostName & MgtHostName corrected the behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, we need to update carbon.xml, uncomment & set HostName & MgtHostName values

```
<!--
Host name or IP address of the machine hosting this server e.g. www.wso2.org,   192.168.1.10 This is will become part of the End Point Reference of the services deployed on this server instance.    -->
<HostName>yourloadbalanced.yourcompany.com</HostName>
<!--    Host name to be used for the Carbon management console    -->
<MgtHostName>yourloadbalanced.yourcompany.com</MgtHostName>
```

Thanks